# why my newcommand reports error?

Tags: macros

### 1

```
\newcommand{\Qf}[3]{\paragraph{\[#1\]}#2\\#3\\}
...
\Qf[AA][AA][AA]
```

it says `There's no line here to end. \Qf[AA`.

### 2

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
...
\csdef{Q1}{
    1.1.2-1992-2,3-1
}  
\csdef{Q1=}{
    $f(x)=e^{x^2},f[\varphi(x)]=1-x,\varphi(x) \geqslant 0,\varphi(x),D(\varphi(x))$
} 
\csdef{A1}{
    $e^{\varphi(x)^2}=1-x \Rightarrow \varphi(x)=\sqrt{\ln (1-x)}\Rightarrow x<1$
}
\newcommand{\toA}[1]{\hyperlink{answer-#1}{answer}\hypertarget{question-#1}{}}
\newcommand{\toQ}[1]{\hyperlink{question-#1}{back}\hypertarget{answer-#1}{}}

\toQ{\csuse{Q1}}
\csuse{Q1=}
\newpage
\toA{\csuse{Q1}}
```

it says `Undefined control sequence. \toQ{\csuse{Q1}}` and `Undefined control sequence. \toA{\csuse{Q1}}`

### 3

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
...
\csdef{Q1}{
    1.1.2-1992-2,3-1
}  
\csdef{Q1=}{
    $f(x)=e^{x^2},f[\varphi(x)]=1-x,\varphi(x) \geqslant 0,\varphi(x),D(\varphi(x))$
} 
\csdef{A1}{
    $e^{\varphi(x)^2}=1-x \Rightarrow \varphi(x)=\sqrt{\ln (1-x)}\Rightarrow x<1$
}
\newcommand{\toA}[1]{\hyperlink{answer-#1}{answer}\hypertarget{question-#1}{}}
\newcommand{\toQ}[1]{\hyperlink{question-#1}{back}\hypertarget{answer-#1}{}}


\Qf[\csuse{Q1}][\toA[\csuse{Q1}]][\csuse{Q1=}]
```

it says `There's no line here to end. \Qf[\csuse{Q1}`

I don't know why, really confuse me in different error-info.

Comment: Ad 1) With `\newcommand{\Qf}[3]{\paragraph{\[#1\]}#2\\#3\\}` you define a macro that takes three mandatory arguments, but `\Qf[AA][AA][AA]` looks more like a macro with three optional arguments. The macro should be called with `\Qf{AA}{BB}{CC}`. This might still not resolve the `There's no line here to end.` issue, though depending on the exact use case of your macro. We'd need to see a full example document and not just snippets to be able to help here, though. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864

Comment: Ad 2) If I load the packages `\usepackage{amssymb}` and `\usepackage{hyperref}` I get no error from those lines of code.

Comment: Ad 3) This combines issues from 1 and 2. Mandatory arguments to a macro must be given in curly brackets, not square brackets. So you need `\Qf{\csuse{Q1}}{\toA{\csuse{Q1}}}{\csuse{Q1=}}`. You also need the packages from 2.

Comment: you are just posting disconnected fragments that makes it hard to test and see the error. Please always post complete small test documents.

Comment: for (1) the three supplied arguments to `\Qf` are  `[`, `A` and `A` which is probably not what you intended.

Comment: I tried to make the first example into a test file but `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Qf}[3]{\paragraph{\[#1\]}#2\\#3\\}

\Qf[AA][AA][AA]

\end{document}` runs without error please make a test file that shows the `no line here to end` error.

Answer (score 2):

It is best to only ask one question per post, and to provide a test file but:

---

**1**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Qf}[3]{\paragraph{\[#1\]}#2\\#3\\}

\Qf[AA][AA][AA]

\end{document}
```

this does not generate the error stated or any error, however the three arguments to `\Qf` are `[`, `A` and `A`.

`\paragraph` is a sectioning command with a run-in heading that is inlined into the first sentence of the paragraph, so using display math `\[\]` in the heading is *very* weird, and in this case the display just consists of `[` with the first two lines from `#2` and `#3` both being A so you get:

[image]

---

**2**

You do not say what error you got, nor give a test file.

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\csdef{Q1}{
    1.1.2-1992-2,3-1
}  
\csdef{Q1=}{
    $f(x)=e^{x^2},f[\varphi(x)]=1-x,\varphi(x) \geqslant 0,\varphi(x),D(\varphi(x))$
} 
\csdef{A1}{
    $e^{\varphi(x)^2}=1-x \Rightarrow \varphi(x)=\sqrt{\ln (1-x)}\Rightarrow x<1$
}
\newcommand{\toA}[1]{\hyperlink{answer-#1}{answer}\hypertarget{question-#1}{}}
\newcommand{\toQ}[1]{\hyperlink{question-#1}{back}\hypertarget{answer-#1}{}}

\toQ{\csuse{Q1}}
\csuse{Q1=}
\newpage
\toA{\csuse{Q1}}
\end{document}
```

Produces the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\toQ #1->\hyperlink 
                    {question-#1}{back}\hypertarget {answer-#1}{}
l.20 \toQ{\csuse{Q1}}

?
```

showing that  `\hyperlink` hyperlink is undefined.

Changing the `\usepackage` line to

```
\usepackage{etoolbox,hyperref}
```

resolves that error, but produces the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\Q1= ...,f[\varphi (x)]=1-x,\varphi (x) \geqslant 
                                                  0,\varphi (x),D(\varphi (x...
l.21 \csuse{Q1=}

?
```

Showing that `\geqslant` is undefined, so changing the `\usepackage` line to

```
\usepackage{etoolbox,amssymb,hyperref}
```

makes the example run without error.

---

**3**

I could not guess how to extend your fragment into an example that gave the stated error.

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{etoolbox,amssymb,hyperref}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Qf}[3]{\paragraph{\[#1\]}#2\\#3\\}

\csdef{Q1}{
    1.1.2-1992-2,3-1
}  
\csdef{Q1=}{
    $f(x)=e^{x^2},f[\varphi(x)]=1-x,\varphi(x) \geqslant 0,\varphi(x),D(\varphi(x))$
} 
\csdef{A1}{
    $e^{\varphi(x)^2}=1-x \Rightarrow \varphi(x)=\sqrt{\ln (1-x)}\Rightarrow x<1$
}
\newcommand{\toA}[1]{\hyperlink{answer-#1}{answer}\hypertarget{question-#1}{}}
\newcommand{\toQ}[1]{\hyperlink{question-#1}{back}\hypertarget{answer-#1}{}}


\Qf[\csuse{Q1}][\toA[\csuse{Q1}]][\csuse{Q1=}]
\end{document}
```

produces the error

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.24 \Qf[\csuse{Q1}
                   ][\toA[\csuse{Q1}]][\csuse{Q1=}]
?
```

as here the three arguments of `\Qf` are `[`, `\csuse` and `{Q1}`

so the `#2\\` in the replacement text of `\Qf` will be `\csuse\\` which is taking the command `\\` as the argument to `\csuse` but as this does not expand to a list of characters it can not form a csname and you get the low level `\endcsname` error shown.

Comment: thank you for your editing.I've solved all the problem.1) \Qf[][][]substitute [] with {} 2), 3) I fogot  importing package